# OIM - PasswordMgmtService.validatePasswordAgainstPolicy : Issue with password history condition in policy being bypassed

Tags: oim

I am working on a custom OIG password management requirement for a client.

I am facing issue while validating the password history in policy definition (eg: shouldn't match last 5 passwords used).

For some reason, **PasswordMgmtService** API's **validatePasswordAgainstPolicy** method is bypassing the history validation and returning true if user enters any old password.

Below is the code snippet for reference.

```
public ValidationResult validatePasswordRACFPolicy(String loggedinUserKey, char[] userPassword)
{     
PasswordMgmtService pwdMgmtSvc = oimClient.getService(PasswordMgmtService.class); 
User usr = new User(loggedinUserKey); //loggedinUserKey is user key of logged in user
ValidationResult valResult = pwdMgmtSvc.validatePasswordAgainstPolicy(userPassword, usr, <App Instance Name>, Locale.getDefault());
IDMLOGGER.log(ODLLevel.FINEST, "Is Password Valid = " + valResult.isPasswordValid()); //this value is true even if user tries to reset password using any older passwords.
return valResult;   
}
```

Eventually, ending up with exception when I try to update the account password on target.

```
provSvc.changeAccountPassword(Long.valueOf(accountId), userPassword);
//provSvc is ProvisioningService API object, accountId is oiu_key, userPassword is the password entered by user.
```

Here are the exception details:

```
GenericProvisioningException An error occurred in oracle.iam.provisioning.handlers.ChangeAccountPasswordActionHandler/execute while changing the password for account with id 1234 and the casue of error is {2}.[[ at oracle.iam.provisioning.util.ProvisioningUtil.createEventFailedException(ProvisioningUtil.java:175) at oracle.iam.provisioning.handlers.ChangeAccountPasswordActionHandler.execute(ChangeAccountPasswordActionHandler.java:84 ... ... Class/Method: tcOrderItemInfo/validatePassword Error : Password Does Not Satisfy Policy
```

Comment: can you post the exception details?

Comment: GenericProvisioningException
An error occurred in oracle.iam.provisioning.handlers.ChangeAccountPasswordActionHandler/execute while changing the password for account with id 1234 and the casue of error is {2}.[[
 at oracle.iam.provisioning.util.ProvisioningUtil.createEventFailedException(ProvisioningUtil.java:175)
 at oracle.iam.provisioning.handlers.ChangeAccountPasswordActionHandler.execute(ChangeAccountPasswordActionHandler.java:84
 ...
 ...
Class/Method: tcOrderItemInfo/validatePassword Error : Password Does Not Satisfy Policy

Comment: can you point me to URL of APIs you are using ? Is it 11GR2PS3? I see your method takes input as `app instance name` which I could not find in APIs

Comment: `clientLogin.getPasswordMgmtService()` also I would like to know `clientLogin is object of which class?`

Comment: Password Management Service API URL:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oim/OMJAV/oracle/iam/passwordmgmt/api/PasswordMgmtService.html#validatePasswordAgainstPolicy_char____oracle_iam_identity_usermgmt_vo_User__java_lang_String__java_util_Locale_

Comment: clientLogin is object of oracle.iam.platform.OIMClient

Comment: Actually I am trying to run same code standalone but its saying "The method getPasswordMgmtService() is undefined for the type OIMClient" I think I need to use `getService()` method of it ?

Comment: As per the documentation `appInstance - name the application instance name to be provisioned` So are you provisioning this application instance and changing the password for the account?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, getPasswordMgmtService is a method in my utility class, please ignore that. Updated the code in question to clear things out. 

appInstance - it doesn't mean app instance is provisioned first and then password. It means for that app instance (target system) the change password has to be provisioned.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Did you created the password policy accordingly and attached to the application instance which you are passing to validatePasswordAgainstPolicy method?